# How to insert foreign key with NULL/None

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to insert a record into my table that has a FOREIGN_KEY that should be able to be empty/null.

Here is the response I get:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "parent_id" violates not-null constraint
```

Here is my model:

```
created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
serve_date = models.DateField()
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
menu_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
        blank=True, null=True, default=None)
item_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, default='')
```

Here is my attempt to insert data:

```
meal = MenuItem.objects.create(serve_date=daily_meals['date'], name=kitchen_meal.name)
```

I also checked the column in my table. It has Not NULL? = Yes

Really not sure what else should be set.

Comment: It looks like you did *not* properly migrate your models. Did you `makemigrations` and `migrate`?

Comment: Several times to make sure.

Comment: Can an error in another table stop a migration? Because I am getting this error for another table: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: could not create unique index "food_v2_ingredient_culinary_name_7a997b99_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (culinary_name)=(frozen, peas) is duplicated.

Comment: yes, since the migrations are done *sequentially*. You thus will first need to solve that error. For example by removing the index manually from the database.

Comment: Guess it can. I skipped this part and now the original problem is solved.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please explain to me that what you mean by migrations are done sequentially. I am curious to know.